# APK is only updated if build from console, not from eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to develop a cocos2d android project.  Something odd is happening. Inside eclipse I edit the source files, however eclipse seems to not be compiling the changeds.  Here is a typical log:

```
[2016-05-29 16:26:28 - GameName] Android Launch!
[2016-05-29 16:26:28 - GameName] adb is running normally.
[2016-05-29 16:26:28 - GameName] Performing org.cocos2dx.cpp.AppActivity activity launch
[2016-05-29 16:26:28 - GameName] Automatic Target Mode: using device '020772d4'
[2016-05-29 16:26:28 - GameName] Uploading GameName.apk onto device '020772d4'
[2016-05-29 16:26:29 - GameName] Installing GameName.apk...
[2016-05-29 16:26:37 - GameName] Success!
[2016-05-29 16:26:37 - GameName] Starting activity org.cocos2dx.cpp.AppActivity on device 020772d4
[2016-05-29 16:26:38 - GameName] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.CompanyName.GameName/org.cocos2dx.cpp.AppActivity }
```

As you can see it is generating a new apk and putting it on the device, however if you edit anything in the project those edits aren't shown. However if you go into command prompt and do `cocos run ...` then it compiles and runs with the changes in your source code.

I have cleaned, rebuilt, relinked etc etc in eclipse and it is still the same story, eclipse does not update the app with the new changes it stays the same.

Am I doomed to compile everything from command prompt?

Also: Eclipse isnt recognizing any errors in my code.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the plugin your using for android. Which plugin are you using? Why are you not using Android Studio? Are you dealing with a legacy software?

Comment: I dont think I am using any legacy software, I just got what was in the cocos2d guide. 2 android SDK's for my two test devices, ANT 1.9.7, Cocos2d-x-3.11.1, Java 1.8, NDK r10c,  Python 2.7.5.    For some reason Android studio cant compile cocos2d so I can unfortunately not use it.

Comment: That sucks, Which version of the android SDK are you using? One I know is not very stable. There is like 3 of them available

Comment: 4.4.2.  I have no loyalty to cocos2d if you know of another equivalent engine (sprites and physics) that is compatible with android studio let me know.

Comment: http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/how-can-i-use-android-studio-together-with-cocos2d-x-any-hints/7365/16

Comment: try looking at this it shows how some got cocos2d working with android studio  batymahn  cntl+f that guys name then he had the same problem

Comment: also check this guy out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gdOkbXYsf04&index=9&list=PLRtjMdoYXLf7fqFlzHJvfhBgO0ddEm-k5